# Header menu full width with background color

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make my header menu stretch across my complete wordpress website width and have a blue background.

I've managed to find the right css selector `.main-navigation`

However, i've tried using `padding`, `margin` and `width` css elements but none seem to do the trick.

You can have a peek at the [site](https://rnltrading.com) to get a better understanding of what I mean.

You can find the css i'm currently using below:

```
.product_meta .posted_in {
    display: none;
}
.product_meta {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.product_meta .sku_wrapper {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 5px;
}
.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
        visibility:hidden;
}
/* Products IN STOCK */
.woocommerce div.product p.stock {
    color: green;
}
/* Products OUT OF STOCK */
.woocommerce div.product p.stock.out-of-stock {
    color: red;
}
/* Products under threshold */
.woocommerce div.product p.stock.low-in-stock {
    color: #FF8C00;
}
.woocommerce-info {
    display: none;
}
```

I'd love to hear your ideas on this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do it with CSS, then this is one way. You need to make the site header container full width and remove the padding. The site navigation will now be full width and you can set the background color to blue.

```
.site-header > .container {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

nav#site-navigation {
    background: #4d90fe;
}
```

However, if you have access to the templates and feel comfortable changing them, change the HTML mark up, and bring the navigation outside the container. Or simply change `container` div class to `container-fluid` (if using Bootstrap 3).

Comment: I see, css would be bad for the SEO. Is this correct? Luckily the site SEO isn't  that import for this website since we have a number of regular customers and they know how to find the website. I've tried using your css snippet and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Also I should add, will this be able to let me change the height too?

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
.main-navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: It did not sadly. it stretches the box across the box width but not the sites width :(